# Is there an R function that can be used in a for-loop for data formatting to a text file?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data set with multiple entries per subject, I want to create one line for each subject with variable inputs in brackets. I tried using the `group-by` function but ended up with a line for each subject with variable values all the same (only subject 1 values were used for all subjects).
Code:

```
mh <- data %>%
 group_by(data$Subject) %>%
 summarise(path = paste(data$y, sep = ",",  collapse = ","),
           days = paste(data$z, sep = ",",  collapse = ","))
```

Now, I'm using a for-loop to organize the data into this format:
Subject 1 [a b c] [2 5 7]; one subject per line

The current format is:

```
Subject  y   z
1        a   2
1        b   5
1        c   7
2        c   5
2        a   10
2        b   12
3        b   4
3        a   9
3        c   14
```

for-loop code:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  print(cat("Subject",i,"["))
  {  append(data$Subject[i], data$y) 
    print(cat("] ["))
  }
  {   append(data$Subject[i], data$z)  
    print(cat("]\n")) 
  }
}
```

I assume I have missed something in the code but could there be a problem with my data set-up as well, maybe the type of data?
Is there another function that I have failed to find?

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping and summarizing were already correct. Here are some tips:

- get comfortable with `paste` and `paste0`, especially the difference between the `sep` option (for separating multiple arguments, like `paste('a', 'b', sep = ",")`) and the `collapse` option (for separating elements of a single argument, like `paste(c(1,2,3), collapse = ",")`).
- look into standard data formats; I don't know what system you're using that expects formats like `[2 4 5]`, but I would just use JSON, like with the packge `jsonlite`.
- explore applying functions, especially with `Map`; then you could write a nice "subject printer" function, and map over your data frame with it; it would be much easier to read and maintain.

Here's how I did it (I kept things close to your original code):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  y = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'),
  z = c(2,5,7,5,10,12,4,9,14)
)

mh <- data %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(
    path = paste0("[", paste(y, collapse = " "), "]"),
    days = paste0("[", paste(z, collapse = " "), "]")
  )

for (i in 1:nrow(mh)) {
  print(paste(
    "Subject",
    mh$Subject[i],
    mh$path[i],
    mh$days[i]
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, when I use this on my data file, for each subject, I get every data point in the brackets for each variable. Just using the code on the small example set it works fine, which makes me think there is something going on with the file. I have tried using a .csv, .txt, and an excel file but I get the same results

Comment: I can't help without access to the data. Try to pin down what's unusual about your data source.